# Hiding gauge series of terminated pods in Grafana

Tags: kubernetes, prometheus, grafana, gauge

I am reporting a certain gauge metric from my application pods. Let's say number of concurrent requests.
After pods were terminated by HPA these series persists with the latest value that was reported.

This is the query I have:

```
kubernetes_gauge_my_app{namespace="my_ns", cluster="my_cluster", key="concurrent_requests", host=~"my_app.\*"}
```

Where host label is actually a pod name. So every time new pod is created,new serie appears and all the old series are still there.

My question is how to hide them?

I have several other count metrics for those apps, one of them is just heartbeat every second. So maybe if heartbeat is not changing over few seconds we can consier this pod dead and hide the series, but don't know how exactly to approach it.

Comment: Prometheus will mark them as stale in a couple of minutes. Do you want to shorten this time, or do I understand your question incorrectly?

Comment: Do you want to hide the old metrics (i.e. suppress them from display on a graph), or do you want to exclude them from calculation (i.e. aggregate the current ones, ignoring stale values)?

Comment: @markalex, strange, cause for me they stay. By the end of the week I have like hundred lines on my graph, while having only 10 actual pods.

Comment: @aecollley, they do no participate in calculations, I display everything by host/pod. I want to hide the stale ones from the graph

Comment: Do you mean you have dashboard with time range `Last 1 week` and see all services for last week? I know that screenshots are discouraged here, but I believe this is exact case to use one. Edit your question and add screenshot, preferably of panel edit page.

Answer (score 0):

Use this selector to filter all metrics that aren't currently present:

```
kubernetes_gauge_my_app{namespace="my_ns", cluster="my_cluster", key="concurrent_requests", host=~"my_app.\*"} and kubernetes_gauge_my_app@end()
```

Here `@end()` return value of metric at the end of time range specified fo dashboard, if it's preset.