# Grafana status history of processes uptime, how to ignore processes that are not active anymore when using broader time range?

Tags: prometheus, grafana, promql

I need help how to setup status history to show my PM2 processes uptime.

This is the status history in last 5 minutes which looks ok,

[image]

Here is the status history metric when I set range to 60 minutes,

[image]

Processes with gray fields at the end (1,2) are dead and will not exist in future because PM2 will not reuse process ID,

what I need is to filter out 'dead' processes (timeseries), this is my current query

```
pm2_status{instance="$service_group"}
```

There is a way to clean up 'dead' processes by adding @ end() at the end of the query but I am not sure is this the right way to do this.

Comment: [I do believe `@end()` approach is the correct one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75998398/21363224). If this answers your question, please, consider closing it as a duplicate.